# Using InvariantCultureIgnoreCase instead of ToUpper for case-insensitive string comparisons

Tags: c#, .net, string, comparison, case-insensitive

*On [this page](http://www.inq.me/post/ASPNet-MVC-Extension-method-to-create-a-Security-Aware-HtmlActionLink.aspx), a commenter writes:*

Do NOT ever use `.ToUpper` to insure comparing strings is case-insensitive.

Instead of this:

```
type.Name.ToUpper() == (controllerName.ToUpper() + "Controller".ToUpper()))
```

Do this:

```
type.Name.Equals(controllerName + "Controller", 
     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

*Why is this way preferred?*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the answer in details .. [The Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) (*read section **3***)

> As discussed by lots and lots of
>   people, the "I" in Turkish behaves
>   differently than in most languages.
>   Per the Unicode standard, our
>   lowercase "i" becomes "İ" (U+0130
>   "Latin Capital Letter I With Dot
>   Above") when it moves to uppercase.
>   Similarly, our uppercase "I" becomes
>   "ı" (U+0131 "Latin Small Letter
>   Dotless I") when it moves to
>   lowercase.
>
> **Fix**: Again, use an ordinal (raw byte)
>   comparer, or invariant culture for
>   comparisons unless you absolutely need
>   culturally based linguistic
>   comparisons (which give you uppercase
>   I's with dots in Turkey)

And according to Microsoft you should not even be using the Invariant... but the Ordinal... (*[New Recommendations for Using Strings in Microsoft .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx)*)

Comment: Thanks...I was suspecting something like this. It's irritating when people say you MUST do something a certain way, but they don't say WHY.

Comment: .. not fond of dictatorships either .. lol .. (*added the microsoft recomendations link*)

Comment: I have also seen a small performance improvement with doing a case-insensitive compare vs. converting to upper/lowercase, so using the comparison flag is definitely the way to go...

Comment: This is funny because for a long time Microsoft recommended using ToUpper instead of ToLower for this exact reason. It's always hard for me to find it but it's on the MSDN site. ... Or maybe it's not anymore. edit: Found it! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 10):

In short, it's optimized by the CLR (less memory as well).

Further, uppercase comparison is more optimized than ToLower(), if that tiny degree of performance matters.

In response to your example there is a [faster way yet](http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2006/01/07/510169.aspx):

```
String.Equals(type.Name, controllerName + "Controller", 
              StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: There's no considerations about weirdness like umlauts, or anything like that?  So this guy was just being a dictator about it?

Comment: @Robert - There are fringe benefits, like free null checking you don't have to worry about, but mainly it's an optimization difference...strings are **highly** optimized by the CLR, so taking advantages of the CLR shortcuts built in can dramatically increase performance if you're hitting that code in a heavy loop.  Also, it'll reduce memory overhead as well.