# hashcode varbinary(20) c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Str1 { get; set; }
    public string Str2 { get; set; }
    public string Str3 { get; set; }
    public string Str4 { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like to create a hashkey, which is persisted in a database as varbinary(20), to determine uniqueness of the class (case insensitive). I guess the usual GetHashCode method could not be used in this case. What would be best practice in this scenario?

Comment: *I guess the usual GetHashCode method could not be used in this case.* You guessed it right :-) +1 just for this! You shouldn't EVER persist a GetHashCode

Comment: What a useful comment (-:

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10452228/613130

Comment: What you said about `GetHashCode` is something very important and quite advanced. I'm sure that 9 out of 10 C# programmers don't know it.

Comment: The solution of usr at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10452967/613130 in particular seems to be very beautiful.

Comment: Why the restriction of varbinary(20)? - Why not use one of the many existing methods?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen such as - I can change the n in varbinary(n).

Comment: I guess by Uniqueness you mean unique Str1, Str2, Str3 and Str4 combination. In that case GetHashCode alone won't be enough to determine it since 2 instances might have the same hash code and different values for these properties.

Comment: yes @vc74 that's correct.

Comment: Couldn't one of the methods in System.Security.Cryptography do the trick?
If needing to be case insensitive and it's just string properties - I'd just dump everything into upper or lowercase when using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Str1 { get; set; }
    public string Str2 { get; set; }
    public string Str3 { get; set; }
    public string Str4 { get; set; }

    public byte[] SHA256()
    {
        using (var sha256 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            var strings = new[] { Str1, Str2, Str3, Str4 };

            for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
            {
                string str = strings[i];

                if (str != null)
                {
                    // Commented lines are for using ToUpperInvariant()
                    //str = str.ToUpperInvariant()
                    byte[] length2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(str.Length);
                    sha256.TransformBlock(length2, 0, length2.Length, length2, 0);

                    // byte[] sortKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
                    byte[] sortKeyBytes = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.GetSortKey(str, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase).KeyData;

                    sha256.TransformBlock(sortKeyBytes, 0, sortKeyBytes.Length, sortKeyBytes, 0);
                } 
                else
                {
                    byte[] length2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(-1);
                    sha256.TransformBlock(length2, 0, length2.Length, length2, 0);
                }
            }

            sha256.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);

            byte[] hash = sha256.Hash;
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using SHA256 and the solution is based on the solution suggested by @usr in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452967/613130 . The generated hash code is 32 bytes long, but you can truncate it to 20 (clearly you'll reduce its uniqueness).

I prepend the length of the various strings to the strings. In this way `{ "ABCD", "", "", "" }` will produce a different hash than `{ "A", "B", "C", "D" }`.

If you prefer you can use good old `ToUpperInvariant()` and hash based on it (there are some commented lines in the code... You uncomment them, remove the `byte[] sortKeyBytes = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and live happy :-) ).

**I have to tell the truth, I'm not sure of the "stability" of `GetSortKey`... Will `GetSortKey` return the same weights in 5 years, in .NET 10.0 with Unicode 11.0? Who knows? I surely don't!**

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.sortkey(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests that they could change:

> If an application serializes a SortKey object, **the application must regenerate all the sort keys when there is a new version of the .NET Framework.**

So in the end I suggest the alternative solution based on `.ToUpperInvariant()` (to be clear, if my boss asked me to do it, I would tell him: use `.ToUpperInvariant()`). Note that even with `.ToUpperInvariant()` there could be small changes in the future. New upper case characters could be introduced for existing lower case characters. See http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html "Can a case pair be added if one of the pair is already encoded?"

Comment: stupid question. this returns byte[32]. Would this mean I have to use varbinary(32) during persistence?

Comment: @csetzkorn Yep, but as I've written, *you can truncate it to 20* `Array.Resize(ref hash, 20)`

Comment: yeah sorry overlooked this bit

Comment: ... Isn't a hash unique only when you use it in its full length?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Clearly by truncating the hash you are reducing its uniqueness. But then, the uniqueness of SHA256 (or of other hashes) is more a stastistical thing... There are too many possible hashes to be probable to find a collision. 20 bytes are still quite much. MD5 has 16 bytes, and was considered secure for many years.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I'll link this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72673/how-bad-is-it-to-truncate-a-hash The response seems to be "depends on how much you are truncating"

Comment: Cryptographic hash algorithms make it hard to create a value that hashes to a specific hash. I don't believe this is an issue here - there is no statement of a security problem in the question. The asker is probably only interested in a good distribution and perhaps fast execution speed.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yep... A [murmurhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) would be perfect. Sadly in .NET the only hashes present are cryptographically strong hashes.

Comment: @csetzkorn I feel like sh#t... I suggested something just because another high rep user had suggested it, and I felt his suggestion was very good... And I liked it, because it was tricky in a good way... But then I thought at it a little. Please read (or reread) my response from *If you prefer you can use good old*. I've update it (various times :-) )

Answer (score 2):

A `varbinary(20)` is 160 bits so you are looking for a 160 bit hash algorithm. The SHA-1 algorithm produces a 160 bit hash value.

It seems that the purpose of your question is to create a hash value that is expected to be unique for a given instance of `SomeClass` so you should favor fast hash algorithms over cryptographic hash algorithms. SHA-1 is a cryptographic algorithm but it is pretty fast and there is an implementation in the .NET Framework. Also, there exists attacks on the SHA-1 algorithm so you should not use it for cryptographic purposes but instead chose algorithms like SHA-256 (that are slower).

All in all I believe that SHA-1 is a good fit for your problem. It is simple to use the algorithm. 1) Concatenate the strings, 2) convert them to upper case, 3) convert them to bytes using a suitable encoding (I use UTF-8) and 4) compute the hash:

```
Byte[] GetHash(SomeClass someClass) {
  if (someClass == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("someClass");

  var byteBuffers = GetStrings(someClass).Select(
    s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
         ? new Byte[0] : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s.ToUpperInvariant())
  );
  var bytes = byteBuffers
    .Aggregate(new List<Byte>(), (l, b) => { l.AddRange(b); return l; })
    .ToArray();
  using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    return sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);
}

IEnumerable<String> GetStrings(SomeClass someClass) {
  yield return someClass.Str1;
  yield return someClass.Str2;
  yield return someClass.Str3;
  yield return someClass.Str4;
}
```

Note that any hash algorithm (also cryptographic algorithms) can and will produce collisions.

Xanatos has a very good point:

> I prepend the length of the various strings to the strings. In this way `{ "ABCD", "", "", "" }` will produce a different hash than `{ "A", "B", "C", "D" }`.

Here is an alternative solution that solves the same problem in a slightly different way where each string length modulo 256 is included in the hash:

```
Byte[] GetHash(SomeClass someClass) {
  if (someClass == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("someClass");

  var byteBuffers = GetBuffers(GetStrings(someClass));
  var bytes = byteBuffers
    .Aggregate(new List<Byte>(), (l, b) => { l.AddRange(b); return l; })
    .ToArray();
  using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    return sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);
}

IEnumerable<String> GetStrings(SomeClass someClass) {
  yield return someClass.Str1?.ToUpperInvariant();
  yield return someClass.Str2?.ToUpperInvariant();
  yield return someClass.Str3?.ToUpperInvariant();
  yield return someClass.Str4?.ToUpperInvariant();
}

IEnumerable<Byte[]> GetBuffers(IEnumerable<String> strings) {
  foreach (var @string in strings) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@string)) {
      yield return new[] { (Byte) (@string.Length%256) };
      yield return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@string);
    }
    else
      yield return new Byte[1];
  }
}
```