# Find duplicate records in a list on two fields by ignoring case

Tags: c#, linq

```
var duplicates = wb.MyList.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.TypeCode, r.InterfaceID,r.ProviderID})
    .Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1);
```

I have two `TypeCode` with different case one is in upper case and other is in lowercase typecode , due to case sensitive it didn't return as duplicates

I have tried with `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` but it gave error. Any other solution?

Comment: `but it gaves error.` - ***what error***?  welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I tried with ToUpper() but it gavescompiler error as Invalid anonymous type declartor

Answer (score 2):

Upper or lower all typecodes for comparison purpose

```
GroupBy(r => new { TypeCode = r.TypeCode.ToUpper(), r.InterfaceID, r.ProviderID })
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "scientific" approach would be to implement a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1), and then group your records using this comparer. The [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1.equals) method of this comparer should check for equality the properties `TypeCode`, `InterfaceID` and `ProviderID` of your records. The comparer could then be used like this:

```
.GroupBy(r => r, new CustomComparer())
```

If you are OK with adding third-party dependencies in your project, you could also consider installing the [Nito.Comparers](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Comparers) package, and create your comparer fluently like this:

```
var myComparer = Nito.Comparers.EqualityComparerBuilder
    .For<MyRecord>()
    .EquateBy(r => r.TypeCode, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ThenEquateBy(r => r.InterfaceID)
    .ThenEquateBy(r => r.ProviderID);

var duplicates = wb.MyList
    .GroupBy(r => r, myComparer)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256453/using-invariantcultureignorecase-instead-of-toupper-for-case-insensitive-string) why using the [`StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer) class is superior to using [`ToUpper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper) for case insensitive string comparisons. The reasons are quite intricate, so in your case the difference might not be important (both approaches might work fine).